# IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'X'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Y'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a trigger that performs a check and automatically populates data into 2 tables. Only what happens the following error :

```
IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'X'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Y'.
```

I found this while researching the error:

"At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.”

So the fix was easy:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON
-- insert statements for table1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table2 ON
-- insert statements for table2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table2 OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table3 ON
-- insert statements for table3
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table3 OFF
```

But as the data is populated via trigger is not possible to do so.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem please?

I apologize.

Thank you all.

Trigger-----

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON registos AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp decimal = 0
DECLARE @id_sensores_em_alerta decimal
DECLARE @tempmin decimal = 0
DECLARE @current_max_idAlarme int = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)
DECLARE @maxidAlarme int
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT s.lim_inf_temp  from sensores s JOIN inserted i ON s.idSensor=i.idSensor )


-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
INSERT alarmes (IdAlarme, descricao_alarme,data_criacao, idRegisto)
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.idRegisto) + @current_max_idAlarme, 'temp Error', GETDATE(), i.idRegisto
    FROM
inserted AS i
    WHERE
i.Temperatura < @temp

SET @maxidAlarme = (SELECT MAX(IdAlarme) FROM alarmes)

INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) 
SELECT i.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
SET @comp += 1;


SET @id_sensores_em_alerta=1;

SET  @id_sensores_em_alerta = (SELECT MAX(id_sensores_em_alerta)  FROM sensores_em_alerta)

INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(id_sensores_em_alerta, idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) 
SELECT @id_sensores_em_alerta, i.idSensor, @maxidAlarme, GETDATE(), @comp
FROM inserted i
end
```

DataBase----

[image]

Comment: And your trigger looks like...?

Comment: Set these Identity insert on/off inside your triggers.

Comment: if the tables will always be populated from a trigger, why do you have identity fields on them.

Comment: On the face of it, if you have so many "identity inserts" to perform, it sounds like you have too many identity columns...?

Comment: Thanks all for reply. Because I need that @HLGEM...Does anyone know of any way to solve this problem? I'm a noob :S

Comment: I would not try and work such complex business logic into a trigger--it will cause logistics and mainteinance nightmares. (In fact, it already has.) Work like this is best implemented as a stored procedure.

Comment: It appears that you are just wanting to insert the next sequential values in the `identity` columns.  Is this correct?

Comment: Which of the fields in which tables are the identities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allow SQL Server to insert the identity values automatically for you.  Since this is a trigger, there could multiple rows being inserted at a time.  For one row inserts, you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to retrieve the identity value of your last inserted row. **However**, since we could have multiple rows inserted in a trigger, we will use the `OUTPUT` clause (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get back a list of the inserted `IdAlarme` values for each `idRegisto`.

I'm assuming that `alarmes.IdAlarme` and `sensores_em_alerta.id_sensores_em_alerta` are the two identity fields in this trigger.  If that is the case, then this should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Alert ON registos AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @comp decimal = 0
DECLARE @id_sensores_em_alerta decimal
DECLARE @tempmin decimal = 0
DECLARE @temp decimal = (SELECT s.lim_inf_temp  from sensores s JOIN inserted i ON s.idSensor=i.idSensor )

DECLARE @tblIdAlarme TABLE (idRegisto int not null, IdAlarme int not null);

-- Insert into alarmes from the inserted rows if temperature less than tempmin
--  IdAlarme is identity field, so allow SQL Server to insert values automatically.
--      The new IdAlarme values are retrieved using the OUTPUT clause http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx
INSERT alarmes (descricao_alarme,data_criacao, idRegisto)
OUTPUT inserted.idRegisto, inserted.IdAlarme INTO @tblIdAlarme(idRegisto, IdAlarme)
    SELECT descricao_alarme = 'temp Error', data_criacao = GETDATE(), i.idRegisto
    FROM inserted AS i
    WHERE i.Temperatura < @temp
;

--It looks like this table needs a PK on both idSensor and idAlarme fields, or else you will get an error here 
--  if an alarm already exists for this idSensor.
INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) 
SELECT i.idSensor, a.IdAlarme, dataAlarme = GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN @tblIdAlarme a ON i.idRegisto = a.idRegisto
;

--not sure what this is doing?? Will always be 1.
SET @comp += 1;

--id_sensores_em_alerta is an identity field, so allow SQL Server to insert values automatically
INSERT INTO sensores_em_alerta(idSensor, idAlarme, data_registo, numerosensoresdisparados) 
SELECT i.idSensor, a.IdAlarme, data_registo = GETDATE(), numerosensoresdisparados = @comp
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN @tblIdAlarme a ON i.idRegisto = a.idRegisto
;

END
```

Answer (score 96):

I had a similar problem but it did not involve table triggers.  I was running a script that refreshes data for multiple tables and I hit a foreign key reference error.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059(v=sql.110).aspx):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
>   property set to ON.

To resolve this, I ran `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table_name] OFF` for each table I was trying to insert into.  Then I was able to refresh my tables again after I corrected the reference error.

Edit: I should also mention that you can just disconnect and then reconnect to reset your session.

Comment: Awesome bro. I was struggled a long time to figure out this issue. 10+

Comment: Seconding @E-A, I had multiple tabs open in SSMS. Once I right-clicked and disconnected all connections (including Object Explorer), closing all sessions, I reconnected and the query worked.

Comment: Just doing it from a new query tab in SSMS works fine.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that this is a session-level setting not a table parameter. I had deleted the identity column from a table after setting insert on and couldn't shut it off! It seemed ridiculous that I'd have to add an identity column just to shut insert off. Disconnect/reconnect worked!