# Confusing IDENTITY_INSERT error, says it is already on in another table

Tags: sql-server, vba

I'm trying to rebuild a database from a text file, using VBA. To insert the ID values, I call this before sending in the INSERTs:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
```

This seems to work fine for most TableNames, but when I call it on table 'Accounts' I get an interesting error:

```
"IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'test.dbo.PropertyAssets'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Accounts'."
```

I'm guessing this has to do with fkey constraints or such, but does anyone know for sure?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you turned on identity insert for `PropertyAssets` but never turned it off.

Comment: ["At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23832598/11683)

Comment: Ahh. Well that's definitely NOT clear from the error message itself,but I get the gist. This gets harder and harder by the second.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can only set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on for one table at a time in your session. If you want to use it on multiple tables, you need to set it `ON` and `OFF` consistently, see the template below:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON

--insert values with IDs

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT PropertyAssets ON

--insert value with IDs

SET IDENTITY_INSERT PropertyAssets OFF
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need another session. I simply reconnected to the same database and it run without any issues.
Of course I changed the script to set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF in the end.

Comment: I reconnected with other User Session, and it run without any issues